# Extracting strings from PE files

Tags: windows, scripting

I'm writing some code (Python, but really isn't important) that analyzes strings inside PE files. I'm looking for a command line tool I could invoke that will return the complete list of strings inside the PE file.

I know PEDUMP, but it seems to give incomplete strings.

Also, it is very important that this tool would be able to handle with different type of strings, such as C-strings (NULL terminated), Pascal-strings (length prefix), etc.

I found "string extractor" [here](http://www.zexersoft.com/products.html), but it costs money and I'm not sure if it can handle different type of strings.

Do you know of any tool that answers my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the classic unix program [`strings`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strings.html) which does exactly this.

Although `strings` isn't specifically designed to handle Pascal-style strings, it will dump them out anyway because they will appear to be textual data.

Some implementations of `strings` can handle Unicode (UTF-8 and UTF-16) strings too.

Comment: First - Thanks.
Second, I've been trying to use cygwin's "strings" on notepad.exe and saw it gives irrelevant information as well (such as imports and gibbrish). Do you know of another option or a version of "strings" for Windows which is better?

Comment: The `strings` program doesn't know what is and is not relevant for you, so it dumps out everything that looks like it could be a string. This will include imports and many other things. If you need only a subset of all possible strings, then you may need another tool, but you're going to have to explain what is and is not "relevant" to you.

Comment: I understand why this isn't as simple as I would like it to be. e.g when running "strings -e l notepad.exe" I get better results, since the strings within are Unicode. I can't be sure this would be the case for every PE.

Comment: I'll start by extracting the strings from the .rsrc section (which are supposed to be the traslate-able strings) and see it this suffice.

Answer (score 0):

http://pedump.me can show all strings from your PE